# why am I able to invoke this C++ standard library function without std:: qualifier?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, argument-dependent-lookup

I'm confused as to why the following code compiles in some cases, but not others.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main(){
  std::vector<int> v(3);
  int a[] = {3, 6, 2};
  std::copy(a, a+3, v.begin());
#define CASE 2
#if CASE == 0
  std::cout << *max_element(a, a+3) << "\n";
#elif CASE == 1
  std::cout << *std::max_element(a, a+3) << "\n";
#else 
  std::cout << *max_element(v.begin(), v.end()) << "\n";
#endif
  return 0;
}
```

I have placed in three cases: CASE 0 fails to compile because there's no such thing as "max_element". I fix this in CASE 1 by changing to "std::max_element" instead, and it *does* compile and works as expected.

However, interestingly for CASE 2 (technically anything but 0 or 1), it also compiles and works. But CASE 2 has the same problem as CASE 0, so why does it work?

Comment: [Argument-dependent lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl).

Comment: @songyuanyao so this code depends on implementation details of `vector::iterator`.  If it were of non-class type then ADL would fail

Comment: if I try defining my own version of max_element, with the same name, and then calling it using CASE 2 above, the compiler complains that "call to max_element" is ambiguous, which I'm assuming means that argument-dependent lookup is making the existing max_element conflict with the one I explicitly defined. Why am I not allowed to do this? Does this mean that argument-dependent lookup is polluting my non-std namespace?

Comment: @M.M Yes you're right definately.

Comment: @xdavidliu because your own function is not in namespace `std`

Answer (score 4):

In the last case, which you denote "CASE 2", the arguments are iterators that for your standard library implementation are of a type define in namespace `std`.

Then *argument-dependent lookup*, more commonly known as just **ADL**, and nowadays less commonly known as Koenig lookup (after Andrew Koenig), finds the function name in that namespace.

---

ADL is the mechanism that e.g. finds the non-member `operator+` for you when you write

```
std::string const a = "Blah";
foo( a + "Blah " );
```

But it can also find ordinary named functions, not just operators.

There is unfortunately no similar mechanism for going the other way, a hypothetical “function-dependent lookup” that e.g. could find a type defined in a class and used in an argument expression for a call of a member function of that class.

---

Since ¹`std::vector` is permitted to use raw pointers as iterators, you are not guaranteed that the code will work with another standard library implementation.

<sup>*Notes:*

¹ `std::vector` and `std::basic_string` guarantee contiguous internal buffers, and this permits raw pointers as iterators.</sup>

Comment: "Since std::vector is permitted to use raw pointers as iterators" I don't think any of the standard library containers are required to use something derived from `std::iterator`.

Comment: @user657267: For example, a `std::list` can't use raw pointers as iterators, because incrementing such an iterator would land you in an arbitrary part of memory (just past or within some allocated node). `std::vector` and `std::basic_string` are special in that they guarantee contiguous internal buffers. And this permits raw pointers as iterators.

Comment: I know, but there's still no requirement that the typedefed type of `std::list::iterator` is defined inside `std`, unless I'm misunderstanding the requirements.

Comment: @user657267: There have been implementations with raw pointers, but AFAIK none with iterators defined in other namespaces. I do not think it's worth cluttering the answer with that possibility. Another unmentioned and far more likely possibility that can make code like this fail, is where the function name is found in two or more namespaces, which can make the call ambiguous.